# Jstree selection limit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have code for jstree, I want to set selection limit to 3, no more than 3 node will be selected.
but this code not working.

```
 $("#mytree").jstree({ 
            "plugins" : [ "themes","html_data", "ui", "crrm","checkbox" ],
            "core" : { "initially_open" : defaultOpen },
            "html_data" : {.............},
            "ui" : {
                     "select_limit" : 3
            },
    ..........
    });
```

Kindly help me.
Thanking You.

Comment: Could you describe in what way it isn't working, and possibly add a working example of the current behavior?

Comment: @SpinyNorman When I select node more than 3, nothing will happen. I am able to select more than 3 nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jstree select\_limit not working. I want to set selection limit to select only 3 nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785236/jstree-select-limit-not-working-i-want-to-set-selection-limit-to-select-only-3)