# Limit the number of selection of child nodes in jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, limit, jstree

I am using jsTree. I want to restrict the child node selection to 4 (either don't allow user to select more than 4 nodes or disable all the checkboxes). I am using select limit which is not working. How can I achieve this?

```
$("#mytree").jstree({ 
    "plugins" : [ "themes","html_data", "ui", "crrm","checkbox" ],
    "html_data" : {
        // ...
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false
    },
    "ui": {
        "select_limit": 4,
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jstree select\_limit not working. I want to set selection limit to select only 3 nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785236/jstree-select-limit-not-working-i-want-to-set-selection-limit-to-select-only-3)

Comment: have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785236/jstree-select-limit-not-working-i-want-to-set-selection-limit-to-select-only-3

Comment: Yes I tried this. Not working

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself.

If you're using jsTree v3+, the "UI" plugin no longer exists and so neither does the "select_limit" property. [This is the current list of plugins that are available.](https://www.jstree.com/plugins/)

If you just wanted a limit of one selection at a time, the core module has a "multiple" property that you can set to true/false as needed. But if you want to limit it to four selections then [the author recommended using the "conditional select" plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jstree/tiNdmxbJakg/A9KVz-FnuDUJ).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need, and i was able to find a solution with a few java script.
    I wanted to have a limit of 3 nodes checked, so i did this :

```
$('#jstree')
    // listen for event
    .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            var i, j, r = [];
            var lenght = data.selected.length;


            for(i = 0, j = data.selected.length; i < j; i++) {
                 if(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).type.localeCompare("child") != 0) {
                    lenght -= 1;
                }
            }


            if(lenght > 3) {

                if(data.instance.get_node(data.selected[data.selected.length-1]).type.localeCompare("child") == 0) {
                    $("#jstree").jstree("uncheck_node", data.instance.get_node(data.selected[data.selected.length-1]).id);
                } else {
                    $("#jstree").jstree("uncheck_node", data.instance.get_node(data.selected[data.selected.length-2]).id);
                }
            }
    })
    // create the instance
    .jstree({
          'core' : 
           ...
```

Comment: No need for `data.instance.get_node(data.selected[data.selected.length-1]).id`
Current node is present in `data` object: `data.node`

Answer (score 0):

Following a conventional method, you can get this task done as follows

```
var children = document.getElementById("mytree").children;
var limit = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < limit; ++i) 
{
    if (!children[i]) return;
    children[i].classList.add("off");
}
```

Comment: I tried above code. I am able to select more than 4 nodes.

Comment: No it is not working. As I said i am able to select more than 4 nodes, I need only maximum of 4 nodes to be selected, if user try to select one more node, the node should not be selected

Comment: have you placed this piece of code within the 'ui:' attribute spec part or created a JS method and called it ?

Comment: No I didn't place the code 'ui' I placed it under "$(element).on('changed.jstree') function. Could you please let me know know where should I place the code exactly?Please provide if you have any working example

Answer (score 0):

Hate to revive an old thread, but I had a request recently from a client to restrict the maximum number of selections for a jsTree based element, and came up with the following solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxSelections = 3;
    $('#maxSelections').on("input", function() {
      maxSelections = $(this).val();
    });
    

    $('#tree').jstree({
      'core': {
        'data': [
          { "text": "Node 1" },
          { "text": "Node 2" },
          { "text": "Node 3" },
          { "text": "Node 4" },
          { "text": "Node 5" },
          { "text": "Node 6" },
          { "text": "Node 7" },
          { "text": "Node 8" },
          { "text": "Node 9" },
          { "text": "Node 10" }
          // Add more nodes as needed
        ]
      },
      'plugins' : [ 'checkbox' ],
      'checkbox' : {
          'keep_selected_style' : false,
          'three_state' : true,
          'cascade' : 'up'
      },
    }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
      // Check if the maximum limit has been reached
      if (data.selected.length > maxSelections) {
        // Deselect excess nodes
        var excessNodes = data.selected.slice(maxSelections);
        $('#tree').jstree('deselect_node', excessNodes);
        alert('Maximum number of selections reached!');
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>jsTree Selection Limit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.11/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
Max Selections: <input type="number" value="3" min=1 max=10 id="maxSelections" />
<div id="tree"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.11/jstree.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```